# Digamma function Identities

Tags: functions, special-functions, digamma-function

I encountered following expression

$$\psi ^{(0)}\left(z+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(z-\frac{1}{4}\right)$$

Searching in different resources I managed to find these identities involving the digamma function $\psi^{(0)}(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln\Gamma(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma (x)}\frac{\mathrm{d} \Gamma (x)}{\mathrm{d} x}$.

1. $\psi ^{(0)}(z+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(z-1)=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}$
2. $\psi ^{(0)}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{z-\frac{1}{2}}$
3. $\psi ^{(0)}\left(z+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(z-\frac{1}{4}\right)=?$

Is there any similar expression for the third case? Or are there any simplification of any other form?

Comment: According to [W|A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolyGamma%5Bz%2B1%2F4%5D-PolyGamma%5Bz-1%2F4%5D), it simplifies to $H_{z - 3/4} - H_{z - 5/4}$ where $H_n$ is a generalization of the harmonic numbers to non-integer indices ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914821/a-generalization-of-the-product-of-harmonic-numbers-to-non-integer-arguments) might be helpful for further reference). I wonder if there is a better simplification/closed form expression for this...

Comment: It is not a simplification (and I'm sure there's none), it's just renaming.

Comment: @metamorphy: Yes, I suspected that it was just renaming using $H_z:=\psi^{(0)}(z+1)$ but wasn't sure if that was a definition for $H_z$ or equivalence with some other definition of $H_z$. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that we can simplify more than you did.

However, making the problem more general, we can write
$$\psi ^{(0)}\left(z+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(z-\frac{1}{n}\right)=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\psi ^{(2 k-1)}(z) }{n^{(2 k-1)}\,(2 k-1)!}$$

If you make $n=4$ and use only $4$ terms in the summation, you have an almost perfect match.